# To import a source into XCode project and stdlib.h in OSX

Tags: macos, xcode, libraries

I want to import the code base [WFDB](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-linux-quick-start.shtml) into XCode.
Source is [here](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb.tar.gz).

In Eclipse, there is a command by which you can import a code base of Zip-file into Eclipse.
It seems that there is no such tool for C-codes.

## Trying to build from scratch in OSX

I run

```
sudo make install
```

I get

```
cd lib;      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make install
cp -p wfdblib.h /usr/include/wfdb; chmod 644 /usr/include/wfdb/wfdblib.h
cp -p ecgcodes.h /usr/include/wfdb
chmod 644 /usr/include/wfdb/ecgcodes.h
cp -p ecgmap.h /usr/include/wfdb
chmod 644 /usr/include/wfdb/ecgmap.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make clean       # force recompilation since config may have changed
rm -f wfdbinit.o annot.o signal.o calib.o wfdbio.o libwfdb.* *.dll *~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make all
sed "s+DBDIR+/usr/database+" <wfdblib.h0 >wfdblib.h
gcc  -fPIC -fno-common -g -O -DWFDB_MAJOR=10 -DWFDB_MINOR=5 -DWFDB_RELEASE=22 -DNOVALUES_H `curl-config --cflags` -I/usr/include -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc   -c -o wfdbinit.o wfdbinit.c
In file included from wfdbinit.c:33:
In file included from ./wfdblib.h:34:
./wfdb.h:417:11: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
# include <stdlib.h>
          ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [wfdbinit.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

**stdlib.h** should not be replaced **unistd.h** according to the second answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400316/what-is-the-location-of-stdlib-h-in-xcode-4-3).

I run

```
find /Applications/Xcode.app -name stdlib.h
```

I get

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h
```

**How can you link the some of the libraries to the code in OSX**

I should have all header files installed in my OSX.
I see only this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install the Command Line Tools. Run the command `xcode-select --install`. That will install headers in the standard system location `/usr/include` rather than only being within the SDK inside of Xcode.

I'm also not sure you should be doing `make install`. It seems to be copying the library's files into `/usr/include` which is definitely not wise. Some programs would use `/usr/local/include`, etc. which is at least better. If this library has a configure script you might want to specify the `--prefix=...` option. You may also be able to override the install directory by specifying `DESTDIR=...` as an argument to `make`.

All of that said, though, depending on your goal, you may be able to just use the built library without requiring that it be installed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You made my day. :)

Comment: Next problem is then with unsupported architecture. I am not sure if there exists any good solution for this. Thread here http://superuser.com/questions/688805/unsupported-architecture-in-installing-linux-program-in-osx

Answer (score 0):

If running `xcode-select --install` does not fix it, the other reason is missing the `/usr/include` folder, installing command-line tools sometimes will not automatically add it.

Install the package at

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```