# Unsupported architecture in installing Linux program in OSX

Tags: linux, macos, installation

I am trying to install the WFDB software for OSX, source [here](http://physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb.shtml).
I run

```
sudo make install
```

I get

```
cd lib;      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make install
cp -p wfdblib.h /usr/include/wfdb; chmod 644 /usr/include/wfdb/wfdblib.h
cp -p ecgcodes.h /usr/include/wfdb
chmod 644 /usr/include/wfdb/ecgcodes.h
cp -p ecgmap.h /usr/include/wfdb
chmod 644 /usr/include/wfdb/ecgmap.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make clean       # force recompilation since config may have changed
rm -f wfdbinit.o annot.o signal.o calib.o wfdbio.o libwfdb.* *.dll *~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make all
sed "s+DBDIR+/usr/database+" <wfdblib.h0 >wfdblib.h
gcc  -fPIC -fno-common -g -O -DWFDB_MAJOR=10 -DWFDB_MINOR=5 -DWFDB_RELEASE=22 -DNOVALUES_H `curl-config --cflags` -I/usr/include -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc   -c -o wfdbinit.o wfdbinit.c
In file included from wfdbinit.c:33:
In file included from ./wfdblib.h:34:
In file included from ./wfdb.h:417:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:71:
In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:655:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from wfdbinit.c:33:
In file included from ./wfdblib.h:34:
In file included from ./wfdb.h:417:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:71:
In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from wfdbinit.c:33:
In file included from ./wfdblib.h:34:
In file included from ./wfdb.h:417:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:71:
In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27:
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:94:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:95:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:96:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:99:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:100:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:101:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:107:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:109:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'
typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:110:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:111:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:131:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:132:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:133:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:134:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
In file included from wfdbinit.c:33:
In file included from ./wfdblib.h:34:
In file included from ./wfdb.h:417:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:75:
/usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h:30:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_intptr_t'; did you mean
      '__darwin_ino_t'?
typedef __darwin_intptr_t       intptr_t;
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:103:26: note: '__darwin_ino_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_ino64_t __darwin_ino_t;        /* [???] Used for inodes */
                         ^
In file included from wfdbinit.c:33:
In file included from ./wfdblib.h:34:
In file included from ./wfdb.h:417:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:80:
/usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h:30:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_size_t'; did you mean
      '__darwin_ino_t'?
typedef __darwin_size_t        size_t;
        ^
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:103:26: note: '__darwin_ino_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_ino64_t __darwin_ino_t;        /* [???] Used for inodes */
                         ^
In file included from wfdbinit.c:33:
In file included from ./wfdblib.h:34:
In file included from ./wfdb.h:417:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:81:
/usr/include/sys/_types/_ssize_t.h:30:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_ssize_t'
typedef __darwin_ssize_t        ssize_t;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [wfdbinit.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2
create a new version of this paste
```

**What is the way to solve the architecture problem?**
I personally think that this problem is a big one and cannot be solved fast.
However, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the "-arch ppc" option from the build command. That specifies to build for PowerPC, which hasn't been supported in many versions of the build tools.

The [WFDB quick start for Mac OS X page](http://physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-darwin-quick-start.shtml) has instructions [at the bottom](http://physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-darwin-quick-start.shtml#ppc) for how to adjust the configuration to turn off building for PowerPC. In general, you should read that page carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer! I was first confused in XCode view what is wrong in the package. Now, I understand why you cannot import the package directly to XCode. You have to take care of the architecture. I did not know about the change of the compiler to Mac's own from gcc.